# How to access contract metadata from another contract?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, nft

I'm building a NFT Marketplace. I already set the mint function (with editions), list and buy function. Now i'm trying to build the auctions functions. On Smartpy, i created the Marketplace class, and now, i set the Auction class, but, if possible, how can i access the contract metadata from the marketplace class? I want to get someinfos from the Marketplace class, like, token_id, editions, owners, etc.
On test, i already tried setting Marketplace class on a variable, and then, using it on Auction, but says:

```
Error: Contracts are not convertible into expressions.



 SmartPy code line 247, in test (line 247)
   auction = Auction(
 SmartPy code line 154, in __init__ (line 154)
   self.init(
 module dc760 line 1373
   setattr(self, k, v)
```

What i tried is something like this:

```
scenario.h1("MarketPlace")
marketplace = Marketplace(
    token_contract.address,
    sp.utils.metadata_of_url(
        "ipfs://QmW8jPMdBmFvsSEoLWPPhaozN6jGQFxxkwuMLtVFqEy6Fb"
    ), admin.address)
scenario += marketplace
scenario.h1("Auction")
auction = Auction(
    marketplace,
    admin.address
)
scenario += auction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SmartPy, contracts can't be used directly as parameters or accessed by other contracts as simple variables.

For your `Auction` contract, you can initialize it with the necessary data from the `Marketplace`'s storage like:

```
auction = Auction(marketplace.data, admin.address)
```

If the data you're after is subject to change, you might consider having the `Auction` contract recognize the `Marketplace` contract's address and make external calls to retrieve data. For this, ensure your `Marketplace` contract provides on-chain views (special entry points that fetch data without state modifications) to return the needed values.